# Developing Retina apps on a 5K Mac

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, retina-display

We are working on an app that will run on an iPad Retina (2,048 x 1,536).  We have a desktop app that is used to test and create content for the iPad app.

The desktop app uses SpriteKit (Mac) and if we load a Retina image (2048x1536) its basically most of the width of the 5K screen ... and is clearly being laid out about 4096 pixels across the iMac display.

Is there a way to get SpriteKit for Mac/Cocoa to use every pixel in its skView?  Such that a 2048 wide image is about 1/4 the size of the iMac 5K desktop?

Comment: Can't you just set the size of the node holding the texture? Or maybe i'm reading the question wrong.